# What's the difference between PlotLabel and PlotLabels?

Tags: plotting, labeling

What's the difference between the option `PlotLabel` and the option `PlotLabels`? In the `Plot` tutorial option list they both exist, so when to use each one of them?

Comment: try: `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0,9}, PlotLabels ->{"sin", "cos"}, PlotLabel->"Sin and Cos"]`

Comment: @JasonB. it exists in built in function Plot.

Comment: @kglr I see but that's confusing

Comment: It may be confusing; but the behavior conforms to the explanation in the "Details and Options" section and the examples in the "Options" section of the documentation for `Plot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PlotLabel` is used to put a label, which may be any expression, centered above a plot's viewport. It is very old — came as part of V1.0, the original Mathematica release made in 1988.

`PlotLabels` is used to label the individual curves shown within a plot's viewport. It is much newer — introduced in V10.4 in 2016 almost 30 years later.

I agree that the naming is confusing. When faced with such confusing option names you should always look at their documentation articles (each has it own) and then experiment with them: kglr's comment gives an excellent example of the kind of experiment you might make.

Comment: Nice answer because you provide a historical background. But do you know that on Stack Overflow questions of this kind are closed as too broad? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#253896). But, is it the right type of questions that we want here and encourage by providing answers that can be easily found with just one click in the manual? Or is it challenging for you as a MA expert?